# Map<int , pair<vector<string>, vector<float>>> m

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Can i use this in my code like :

```
Map<int, pair<vector<string>, vector<float>>> T;
```

Is this the right practice to write STL??

Comment: You can have `std::map<int, std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<float>>> T;` without any problem. Also you should describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but will future you remember what that all corresponds to? I prefer giving things meaningful names.

E.g. you might want to define

```
struct Element {
    std::vector<std::string> names; // ?
    std::vector<float> values; // ?
}
```

And use it in your map

```
std::map<int, Element> elements_by_id; // ?
```